# Android studio update compile sdk version

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, target-sdk

I an using android studio in Ubuntu. I want to update compile sdk version. Now I can select "API 23: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)" as maximum version.

**Project Structure Window**

[image]

Now I want to Increase This. What should I update from SDK manager. I want to update things least as possible because have slow and limited internet connection.

Answer (score 5):

Please go to the `build.gradle` file of your project and find this line:

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
```

Change the number to whatever you want (current max is 25). Then try to build and if you are missing the API in your SDK, you will get an error with instructions on how to download it :-)